# How do I unlock the daily surprises?

Tags: star-wars, advent-calendar

I got a lego star wars 2012 advent calendar (9509), and on the back it say "unlock a surprise every day", and it says to go to legostarwars.com, and there's a code on the back of the advent calendar flap, but when I go to legostarwars.com, it redirects(?) me to a lego star wars III clone wars game experience, and I don't know where to enter the code. Where am I supposed to enter the code?

Comment: The durability of LEGO products usually outlasts anything they do digitally, and this is no exception - as of april 2013, the action has long ended and the page to enter the code doesn't exist anymore. As such, this question isn't likely to help future visitors, hence the closing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not the URL you're looking for ;)

Apparently you need to enter the codes on the [LEGO.com Star Wars Advent Calendar](http://starwars.lego.com/en-us/advent/Default.aspx) page.

Answer (score 0):

The codes are:

```
obiwan:MYONLYHOPE 

GREEDO:HESHOTFIRST 

HAN SOLO: NERFHERDER 

leia:YOURWORSHIPFULNESS 

VADER:MOSTIMPRESSIVE 

SIDIOUS:DARKSIDE 

LANDO:CLOUDCITYGAMBLER 

BOBA:SARLACCFOOD 

LUKE:KISSEDMYSISTER 

CHEWBACCA:LETTHEWOOKIEEWIN 

SAVAGE OPRESS:OPPRESSIVEMAUL
```